# Adaptive payments in IOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, paypal, payment

I am looking to have a parallel payment built into the app so that the user can Use the CARD.IO feature of the new IOS SDK to purchase the item , but then payment is sent to 2 different vendors

Is this possible?

Comment: what kind of item you are selling through app?

Answer (score 0):

Chained/Parallel payments like this are not supported by version 1.0 of the new PayPal mobile SDKs.